# Trailing where clause for extension of non-generic type

Tags: ios, swift, protocol-extension, swift2

I have the following code:

```
func registerNotification(name:String, selector:Selector)
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: selector, name: name, object: nil)
}

func registerKeyboardNotifications()
{
    let isInPopover = navigationController?.popoverPresentationController != nil
    let ignore = isInPopover && DEVICE_IS_IPAD
    if !ignore {
        registerNotification(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"))
        registerNotification(UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"))
    }
}
```

in an extension to `UIViewController`. This code is reused by many viewcontroller to register for keyboard notifications. However with Swift 2.2 it produces a warning. I like the new `#selector` syntax but not sure how to implement it in this case.

I think the correct solution is to make a protocol and extend `UIViewController` only for instances that conform to that protocol. My code so far:

```
@objc protocol KeyboardNotificationDelegate
{
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification)
    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification)
}

extension UIViewController where Self: KeyboardNotificationDelegate
{
    func registerKeyboardNotifications()
    {
        let isInPopover = navigationController?.popoverPresentationController != nil
        let ignore = isInPopover && DEVICE_IS_IPAD
        if !ignore {
            registerNotification(UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, selector: #selector(KeyboardNotificationDelegate.keyboardWillShow(_:)))
            registerNotification(UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, selector: #selector(KeyboardNotificationDelegate.keyboardWillHide(_:)))
        }
    }
}
```

However this get me the error

```
trailing where clause for extension of non-generic type
```

on the extension row. Any ideas?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The solution was simple to switch the order in the extension clause:

```
extension UIViewController where Self: KeyboardNotificationDelegate
```

should be

```
extension KeyboardNotificationDelegate where Self: UIViewController
```

Comment: This hugely helped me. I was doing the other way around, `extension UIViewController where Self: UICollectionViewDelegate` but I didn't realize it needed to be flipped with the delegate on the left.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question! That helps!

Answer (score 23):

`extension Foo where ...` can only be used if `Foo` is

1. a generic class or structure: extend with a default implementation for generics conforming to some type constraint,
2. a protocol containing some associated types, extend with a default implementation for when an associated type conform to some type constraint
3. a protocol where we extend with a default implementation for when `Self` is of a specific (object/reference) type, or conforms to some type constraint.

E.g.

```
// 1
class Foo<T> { }
extension Foo where T: IntegerType {}

struct Foz<T> {}
extension Foz where T: IntegerType {}

// 2
protocol Bar {
    associatedtype T
}
extension Bar where T: IntegerType {}

// 3
protocol Baz {}
extension Baz where Self: IntegerType {}

class Bax<T>: Baz {}
extension Baz where Self: Bax<Int> {
    func foo() { print("foo") }
}

let a = Bax<Int>()
a.foo() // foo
```

In your case, `UIViewController` is a non-generic class type, which does not conform to any of the two above.

---

As you've written in your own answer, the solution is to extend your delegate protocol with a default implementation for cases where `Self: UIViewController`, rather than attempting to extend `UIViewController`.